# What is the best way to restrict /proc fs from malicious users (linux)?

Tags: linux, mount, kernel, security, proc

I am trying to make a restriction to procfs like only a certain groups of members can perform read and write actions.

[kernel document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) says we can do that by setting `hidepid` and `gid` in `/etc/fstab`. It will restrict the malicious user from making read and write on procfs but I have a doubt whether it is possible for malicious user (restricted in the `/etc/fstab`) to access content in profs using syscall instead of fs operation like read and write.

Comment: I think that `/proc` and syscalls use the same security model. I am not an expert. I hope someone that is can answer.

Comment: Is there some content in `/proc` you particularly want to limit? There's a bunch of different stuff there, process information, sysctls and... well, other stuff.

Comment: What system call do you think will reveal information that's also available in `/proc`?

Comment: @ilkkachu I want to limit everything that is sensitive like `environ`, `cmdline` etc.

Comment: @AndyDalton I am not expert in `/proc` so I am just using asking whether it is possible by syscall, I am not saying it is possible and how to block.

Comment: "Operations like read and write" ARE SYSCALLS, so I cannot see how this Q can make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc` *is* the interface between the kernel and userspace for all its contents, and most of those contents aren’t available in any other way (for content under pid directories, outside of that process). So `hidepid=2` is effective in hiding information such as a process’ command line and environment from other users.

Some information can be determined through side effects. For example the existence of a process with a given pid can be determined by attempting to kill it, with signal 0: `kill()` fails with `ESRCH` if a process doesn’t exist, `EPERM` if the calling process doesn’t have the right permissions. Similarly, open ports can be determined by attempting to connect to them.

Comment: Tnx Stephen, nice catch. It is interesting, If there any other side effects that expose the information kindly share her so that we will also know what are the vulnerabilities still exist even if we apply `hidepid=2`